# Accidentally created a Microsoft account for Windows 8 - now settings are gone

Tags: windows-8

I'm new to Windows 8 and used my laptop without a "Microsoft account". A few hours ago I setup the Microsoft Mail program and now my hotmail.com email address and password is the one to login to my laptop instead of my previous login data. Also some of my custom settings are gone (for the mouse and touchpad). What do I need to do to get my original login back?

Comment: Disconnect your local user account from the Microsoft Account or change those settings again, since your technically logged into an entirely separate user, or manually transfer those files from your old profile.

Comment: Many of the store apps require a Microsoft account - e.g. Calendar. So before you go back to a local account, you may want to consider that.

Comment: As @whs points out, the Mail program that uses the Metro interface DOES require you to be signed in with your microsoft account. Hence the reason it got converted in the first place. If you, however, install Windows Live Essentials, which includes Windows Live Mail, you do not need to have a microsoft account. You need to be logged in on the website to download it, but thats it.

Answer (score 0):

As Ramhound mentioned, you will need to diconnect your local account from your Windows Live account. That will in turn change the login to a local username and password. See [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/quick-tip-change-microsoft-live-to-a-local-account-in-windows-81/).